# Setting Calendar Event From Date Picker

Tags: ios, events, date, calendar

I am setting a calendar event from code in my app, and setting the date from my date picker. Here is what I have:

```
-(void)setCalenderEvent
{
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    NSDate *startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *endDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    event.title = @"Test from date picker";
    // event.startDate = startDate;
    // event.endDate = endDate;
    NSDate *selectedDate = self.datePickerForReminder.date;
    event.startDate = selectedDate;
    event.allDay = NO;
    event.notes = @"Created by Quick Reminders!!";
    /* iOS 6 requires the user grant your application access to the Event Stores */
    if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
    {
        /* iOS Settings > Privacy > Calendars > MY APP > ENABLE | DISABLE */
        [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if ( granted )
             {
                 NSLog(@"User has granted permission!");
                 [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
                 NSError *err;
                 [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
                 if (err == noErr){
                     NSLog(@"No Error");
                 }
                 [startDate release];
                 [endDate release];
                 [eventStore release];

             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"User has not granted permission!");
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: This is the error I get: 2013-07-13 00:06:07.260 Reminders[1399:1003] Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=3 "No end date has been set." UserInfo=0x1753f660 {NSLocalizedDescription=No end date has been set.}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it! You need a span time (add end time).

```
event.endDate = [selectedDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:30*60];
```